# How do I set a thumbnails background on-hover using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, css

When users hover over a small thumbnail I want that image to replace the background image.

How can I do this using Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: What have your tried? Where's your code? Without these answers we can do nothing but guess

Comment: I was trying to find the answer with JavaScript but couldnt figure out what to make the function do. For example, I am not calling an element id... So I have no idea what to call.

Comment: You don't have to use an ID in my example Frank, you can use an element type e.g. img, or anything you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('thumbnail id').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image','new image');
});
```

Comment: I feel really sorry... I was currently trying to undownvote but it's locked

Comment: If you edit it (to indent for example) i will be able to undownvote

Comment: And if feel stupid too... Once again i beg for your pardon. I it's me who should have read twice :=(

Comment: Thanks, don't worry, I genuinely apologise for my comments though, they were insulting and unnecessary and yeah, I did not mean to be out of order, hope that's ok.

Comment: Don't worry, down-voting without double-checking is really bad. Your anger was totally understandable. I insist on my wrongness

Comment: That's fine but it was no reason for me to be rude and personal, I think I was the one acting childish. Anyway best wishes and lets forget about that now!

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery's hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) would take care of this.  Basically you want to get the image and set its hover functions to set the background image (and unset on hover out if that is your desired behavior)

```
$('#tumbnail_id').hover(function() {
    // set the background
}, function() {
    // unset the background
});
```

assuming your tumbnail HTML tag has an id of `tumbnail_id`.  You can do some more clever stuff with your selectors and CSS classes if you have several thumbnails, but this is the basics of adding in your hover functionality.

Comment: Thanks, Im going to look into this a little more.